# How can i convert this HATEOAS format json to a model object in android?

Tags: android, rest, android-volley, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I'm learning both Spring and Android. Using Spring Data JPA I have created a JSON api which is in HATEOAS form. I am having problem on parsing them in android. I am using Volley to deal with api.

I have been able to retrive the data from simple json format.Since I am new to android I don't have good knowledge on Parsing tha HATEOAS formatted json

I can deal with the api that looks like this

```
 {
   "image" : "imageName",
   "releaseDate" : "01.05.2016",
   "name" : "name"
 }
```

but I don't have any idea of how to deal with api that looks like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "firstName": "Alexander",
        "lastName": "arnold",
        "email": "trentarnold@liverpool.com",
        "password": "cornertakenquickly",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/1"
          },
          "customer": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "tester",
        "email": "dulalsujan911@gmail.com",
        "password": "12345678",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/2"
          },
          "customer": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/customers"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

here is my android code for retriving simple api:

```
 final String BASE_URL ="http://192.168.1.67:8080/api/customers";
   // final String BASE_URL ="http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/customers";

    // creating a request ques for HTTP request
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Setting HTTP GET request to retrieve the data from the SERVER
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,BASE_URL
            ,null
            , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // creating gson object to convert JSON file
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            //gets the array response
            // now parsing the array into the value
            Log.d(response.length()+"", "onResponse: ---------------------");
            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                try {
                    String json = response.getString();
                    Customer customer = gson.fromJson(json,Customer.class);
                   passwordList.add(customer.getPassword());
                   emailList.add(customer.getEmail());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(e.getMessage(), "onResponse: ------------JSON Prasing exception-----------");
                }
            }

        }

        } , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("REST error",error.toString() );
        }
    }

    );

    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a java class from that model instead of parsing it manually? Then you can use Gson to parse it for you. You don't even have to do it manually. You can use e.g. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate the class for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *https://app.quicktype.io/* or *http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/* to generate the model class. Or Simply use this plugin an android studio *https://github.com/zzz40500/GsonFormat* which will generate model class